# How to search for special characters on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, search

Which I search for something like `"f-script"` it seems like the `-` is ignored?  Can I have special characters in my search terms or is it not supported?

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.symbolhound.com as a tool for searching SO (and in the future, many other programming sites and forums). A search for "f-script" on symbolhound yields: http://symbolhound.com/?q=f-script .

Hope that helps!
-Tom (co-founder)
SymbolHound - The Special Character Search Engine for Programmers

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 0):

[You can now search for hyphenated terms like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) by using quotes, like this: ["f-script"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22f-script%22)