# How can I search for special characters?

Tags: bug, search, search-engine, special-characters

### Situation:

It started out as me [trying to search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22C-c%22) for the literal string `C-c` in https://vi.stackexchange.com/ but it ended up omitting the `-` sign and showing results which contained the strings `C/C++` and `C & C++`.

[This](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/300/other-ways-to-exit-insert-mode-besides-escape/) is an example of a post which contains that string of characters (yet fails to show up in the results).

---

#### Things I've tried:

1. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153438/does-the-so-search-engine-require-escape-characters) post suggests that I can use the undocumented `code:` operator, but when I do that, it just wraps the whole term in double quotes like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22C-c%22).
2. As @terdon in Unix & Linux chat has [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24723956#24723956), using this [Symbolhound query](http://symbolhound.com/?q=+%22C-c%22+) does yield some relevant results, but it doesn't show me [the entry](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/300/other-ways-to-exit-insert-mode-besides-escape/) that is supposed to be there.
   **edit**: It appears that the Symbolhound query no longer returns that result.
3. Finally, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) says that you can search for literal characters, but as you can see:

> Quoted phrases are ***exact*** matches except for case-sensitivity, for example, you can search [for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22COUNT%28%2a%29+AS+UpVotes%22) or [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%2a=%22).

The second example (symbols) leads to 0 results.

---

So by now I assume that the search engine has changed (but the old documentation still lingers on this site). Is there a method for me to search for strings that include special (or is it literal?) characters?

Comment: Well, according to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161789/152859) it should be possible with quotes. Since it's not, this might be a bug

Comment: @sha and marked as such

Comment: One workaround I've found that sometimes works on punctuation, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work for `C-c`, is to use google's search engine at google.com.  
For example, you can search for ||: and find an appropriate result.

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 9):

As it seems now, this isn't possible indeed and since it is documented it can, it seems to be a bug. I have tried all methods described in your post, in the Advanced search tooltip and the [Searching topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the help. Nothing seems to be able to match a minus sign (or any special character).

A last resort might be (at least for now) to use SEDE to [get the data you want](https://data.stackexchange.com/vi/query/375986/get-posts-with-c-c-in-their-body).

Comment: Thanks, there's also [this query](http://symbolhound.com/?q=+%22C-c%22+) from Symbolhound, and I've edited my original question to reflect that.

Comment: -1 as this doesn't answer the question, other to suggest this might be a bug.