# Searching for exact phrase matches spaces for underscores

Tags: bug, search, exact-phrase-search

I ran a Stack Overflow search for `[rspec][capybara] "with_text"`, expecting to find only results containing the phrase `with_text`. However, the first result is [expected css "title" with text in capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269445/expected-css-title-with-text-in-capybara), which does not contain the phrase `with_text`.

It does contain `with text`, though.

Surely, as the quote marks are advertised as constraining to an exact match, it should match the exact string that's typed (case notwithstanding) and not mess around substituting spaces for underscores? Underscores *are* quite common in SO search terms…

Comment: Are you certain that there _are_ any exact match results? I tried [writing a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/854819) to find the "correct answers" for testing. After taking forever and a half to execute, it came back with about 20 results, and none of the ones I spot-checked actually contained the exact phrase "with_text". So maybe the search is confusingly attempting to be helpful by guessing at close things you might want? That's my working theory, anyways.

Comment: Those searches with symbols has been haunted for a long time, hence [symbol hound](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267937/how-can-i-search-for-special-characters/298440#298440) ...

Comment: @SOLO Possibly, but I'd prefer to see a message in that case, rather than just a set of results that I have to click on to find they're not what I wanted. Maybe something like Amazon does: show the search terms with a strikethrough on the one that's being omitted?

Comment: That makes sense. The varying levels of hinting in the UI around here (sometimes you're told immediately you can't do a thing, other times you put a bunch of effort into something before you're told it's restricted) can be confusing. As for your specific issue, I did a bit more work after writing my first comment, and I'm just baffled. Using IoT as a test site, I'm getting proper handling of [a search string containing underscores](https://iot.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22single_chan_pkt_fwd%22) with no similar-but-inexact matches.