# Can a search include mathematical expressions?

Tags: support, search, mathjax

It's difficult to search for math-related topics without using math expressions. Can this be done somehow? I'm talking about things beyond +, - , / , etc.

Comment: Related: *[How can I search for special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267937/how-can-i-search-for-special-characters)*. But [SymbolHound](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Symbolhound) [is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267937/how-can-i-search-for-special-characters#comment1283690_267937).

Comment: Maybe using SEDE? Although it would be a giant amount of data, the data dump might be of use. Note that they only update every so often though. Also, the data dump might be manageable if you pick a smaller site to limit your search to. But it would likely be at least somewhat complicated for the data dump

Comment: SEDE can work but you need to be precise and limit the posts to search: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1714508?tagname=algebra-precalculus&mathjax=%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D(8+%2B+x)%5E%7B2%7D+%2B+16(8+%2B+x)%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D